# Backpropagation() to file

Tags: c++, class, matrix, methods, ofstream

I wanna get backPropagation proccess into a file in the most detail possible.
I've tried adding ofstream File as Attribute for Matrix class to write methods results via ofstream append to file but then most Matrices in SimpleNeuralNetwork class were marked with error (for example _weightMatrices).

```
class SimpleNeuralNetwork
{
    public:
        std::vector<uint32_t> _topology;
        std::vector<Matrix2D<float>> _weightMatrices;
        std::vector<Matrix2D<float>> _valueMatrices;
        std::vector<Matrix2D<float>> _biasMatrices;
        float _learningRate;
    public:
        
        // topology defines the no.of neurons for each layer
        // learning rate defines how much modification should be done in each backwords propagation i.e. training
        SimpleNeuralNetwork(std::vector<uint32_t> topology,float learningRate = 0.1f)
            :_topology(topology),
            _weightMatrices({}),
            _valueMatrices({}),
            _biasMatrices({}),
            _learningRate(learningRate)
        {

bool backPropagate(std::vector<float> targetOutput)
        {
            if(targetOutput.size() != _topology.back())
                return false;

            // determine the simple error
            // error = target - output
            Matrix2D<float> errors(targetOutput.size(), 1);
            errors._vals = targetOutput;
            errors = errors.add(_valueMatrices.back().negetive());
            

            // back propagating the error from output layer to input layer
            // and adjusting weights of weight matrices and bias matrics
            for(int32_t i = _weightMatrices.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                
                //calculating errrors for previous layer
                Matrix2D<float> prevErrors = errors.multiply(_weightMatrices[i].transpose());

                //calculating gradient i.e. delta weight (dw)
                //dw = lr * error * d/dx(activated value)
                Matrix2D<float> dOutputs = _valueMatrices[i + 1].applyFunction(DSigmoid);
                Matrix2D<float> gradients = errors.multiplyElements(dOutputs);
                gradients = gradients.multiplyScaler(_learningRate);
                Matrix2D<float> weightGradients = _valueMatrices[i].transpose().multiply(gradients);
                
                //adjusting bias and weight
                _biasMatrices[i] = _biasMatrices[i].add(gradients);
                _weightMatrices[i] = _weightMatrices[i].add(weightGradients);
                errors = prevErrors;
            }
```

}

Comment: Please be more specific than "marked with error". If you got error messages, include them in the question. If these are "live" errors (e.g. IntelliSense), you can ignore them if the code compiles.

Comment: A `std::ofstream` can't be copied, so objects that have one as a member can't be copied either. What is it you want to accomplish? One file per matrix? One file for all matrices? Shared files in some complex configuration? One file for each back propagation?

Comment: @molbdnilo Ideally 1 file for all matrices

Comment: @molbdnilo error: `function "Matrix::operator=(const Matrix &)" (declared implicitly)`

Comment: Open one stream, pass a reference to `backPropagate`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thx it works !
Is there a way to integrete writing to file for a class ?
I've tried making ofstream as class Attribute but then memebers of this class returned error in my neuron network class. I'll try look for specific error message cuz so far I have problems replicating it.

Comment: As I said, you can't copy `std::ofstream` objects. You can replicate the problem with `struct A { std::ofstream s; }; int main() { A a; A b; a = b; }`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Okay, It's there a way to pass stream to methods ? I've tried adding a reference the same way as for backPropagation (as argument) but methods didn't write anything.